# NHibernate Java style mapping

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

When you map an entity with Java Hibernate it's easy and all you have to do is annotate the class itself. For example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="students")
public class Student implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private Integer uniqid;

    @Column(name="first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private List<Address> addressesList;
}
```

I am trying to use NHibernate on a .NET WCF project.

Can I use meta-tags to map entities like I do in Java normal hibernate?

Comment: It is possible, but no one does it. Everyone uses XML mappings or Fluent NHibernate. So the class doesn't become dirty with attributes.

Comment: Thanks, I am a Java developer so I prefer the annotations style, but I will use XML, if this is the way chosen by .NET people. Thank you.

Comment: There is also the built-in mapping-by-code. Both this and Fluent NHibernate has the advantage of intellisense and conventions to reduce typing.

Comment: I agree with @OskarBerggren. Once you get used to intellisense and the mapping-by-code, you'll spend much less time configuring your mappings, and they will be more resistant to refactoring if you use the `Rename` feature in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is available in the NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes namespace. You can download the most recent version [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nhcontrib/files/NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes/) for NH 3.2.0GA.